# Xpages: Cannot get partial refresh working in dialog box

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, partial-page-refresh

Xpage contains a dialog box with two fields. I only want to display the second field for a certain value in the first field. I am trying to use a partial refresh, but I cannot get it to work.

I have tried changing the scope variables to different things, but this doesn't help.

It seems like this should be pretty easy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:applicationScope.status                   = ["1 Not Assigned","2 Assigned","3 Being Developed","4 Ready For User Test","5 Ready to Migrate to Production","6 Closed"];
applicationScope.assignedTo             = ["Not Assigned","Tanner Jessee","Vijay Somisetti"];    
applicationScope.assignedTo2            = ["Tanner Jessee","Vijay Somisetti"];
applicationScope.reason                 = ["User Training","System Availability","Configuration/Development Bug","Other"];   
sessionScope.newStatus = "None"
 }]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:button id="button13" value="Promote"
        style="font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt">

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.status = "2 Assigned"
viewScope.action = "P";
var d = getComponent('dialogAction');
d.show();}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>    
    <xp:br/>
    <xp:br/>
    <xp:panel id="pnlTicket" style="width:600px"><xe:dialog style="width:600px" id="dialogAction" refreshOnShow="true">
        <xp:div align="center">
            <xp:table style="margin-left:0.0px;margin-right:0.0px;width:560px;margin-top:5.0px;margin-bottom:5.0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
                <xp:tr id="tblPromote">
                    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.action == "P"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                    <xp:td style="width:100px;float:left" align="left">
                        <xp:label value="Promote to..." id="label4"/>

                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:350px;float:right" align="right">
                        <xp:comboBox id="newStatusP" style="width:200px" value="#{sessionScope.newStatus}">
                            <xp:selectItems>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var curSts:String = viewScope.status
var tmpArr = [];

if (curSts != "6 Complete")

{var stsArr:Array = applicationScope.status;
var nmb = stsArr.indexOf(curSts) + 1;

for (i = nmb; i < 6; i++) { 
    tmpArr.push(stsArr[i])
}
}
tmpArr}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlTicket"/>

                        </xp:comboBox>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr id="tblReasonClosed">
                    <xp:td style="width:100px;float:left" align="left">
                        <xp:label value="Reason Closed..." id="label9"/>                    
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:350px;float:right" align="right">
                        <xp:comboBox id="comboBox6" style="width:200px;float:right" value="#{viewScope.assign}">
                            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.newStatus == "6 Closed"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                            <xp:selectItems id="selectItems5">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:applicationScope.reason}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:selectItems>
                        </xp:comboBox>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>    
            </xp:table>
        </xp:div>
        <xe:dialogButtonBar>
            <xp:button value="OK" id="button21">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlTicket">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialogAction}')]]></xp:this.script>
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://Do Stuff}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
            <xp:button value="Cancel" id="button20">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialogAction}')]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField9" value="#{sessionScope.newStatus}"/>          
        </xe:dialogButtonBar>
    </xe:dialog>
  </xp:panel>
```

Additions:

Thank, Mike, for your suggestions. I ran across a very [interesting blog post by Mark Rodin.](http://xomino.com/2013/09/22/making-xpages-partialrefresh-work-in-a-bootstrap-3-dialog-box/) He explains the reason why this won't work out of the box, which is essentially that the dialog box is not in the DOM. He has a work around which I want to try soon, but I found a workaround for the current project. My underlying doc is in read mode when the dialog box is called, so I just changed the partial to a complete refresh. Complete overkill? Yes. But it works and I don't notice any speed issues.

I am going to try to get it to work correctly in the future.

Comment: Can't delve into it right now, but some ideas off the top of my head. There's a property for xe:dialog `partialRefresh="true"`, which may help. Might also be worth wrapping the content in the dialog inside a dialogContent control, and partial refreshing that.

Comment: I tried that property but it did not work. I have not tried the wrapping yet. I do think I understand the problem better. Please see additions to my original question.

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler The dialog starts off in the DOM, just not in the `form` (so not part of what gets submitted back to the server). What Marky demonstrates is re-appending it back into the `form` element via CSJS.

Answer (score 0):

You're onchange event is partially refreshing an area **outside** the dialog. If you refresh an area inside the dialog, you should be fine.

Comment: Paul, I was updating the panel which contains the dialogbox. I changed it to doing a partial update on the dialogbox itself, and when I change the value, the dialog box just closes?

Comment: You shouldn't update the panel that CONTAINS the dialog (that may cause other issues then) but update an element INSIDE the dialog itself. If you don't have anything particular inside it just add a xp:div around your two fields.

Comment: Oliver, I tried that and it did not work. I can do a full update and it will work, so I am good with that for now. I run a process that updates the document when a user presses the button. Then I dismiss the modal dialog box. When I do that I want to reload the underlying document. How do I do that?

Comment: It looks like a full refresh is the only way to refresh the dialog. It's the method used in the Extension Library demo database. I'm presuming this is to do with DOM manipulation that needs to take place because of how Dojo handles dialogs.